# Oracle join of combination

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following tables with their corresponding columns:

```
Order_head (order_no, supplier)
Order_item (order_no, item, country)
Supplier_Country (supplier, item, country)

Order_head:
order_no   supplier
  100        2000

Order_item
order_no   item   country
  100      001   
  100      002

Supplier_Country
supplier   item   country
  2000     001      SA
  2000     002      US

The Country Column in order_item should be filled as per the info in Supplier_Country Table 

Order_item
order_no   item   country
  100      001      SA   
  100      002      US
```

Order_head and Order_item are joined by order_no.

I want to fill the country column in the Order_item - based on the criteria that the combination of SUPPLIER from order_head and ITEM from order_item is matched with supplier and item in Supplier_Country Table.

How should i go with it?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also clarify whether you are looking to update the data or just return data in a particular format.

Comment: Have added the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Country is on the Supplier Country Table, you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE OI
SET Country=SC.Country
FROM Order_item OI
INNER JOIN ORDER_HEAD OH
on OI.Order_No=OH.Order_No
INNER JOIN Supplier_Country SC
on OH.Supplier=SC.Supplier 
and OI.Item=SC.Item
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that `item` column in your `Supplier_Country` table a bit odd. But according to your info, I think this is the `update` statement:

```
update Order_item oi
set oi.country = (select sc.country
                    from Order_head oh
                    join Supplier_Country sc
                      on sc.supplier = oh.supplier
                     and sc.item = oi.item
                   where oh.order_no = oi.order_no)
```